# sticking stickies to windows

Tags: software-rec, gui, desktop

I'm looking for a sticky notes/knotes/etc type program with one difference: I can stick a note on a window, rather than the desk top, and it will remain attached to the window.

Basically, I want to be able to annotate windows. I want to be able to say "this xterm is the one where I'm doing project X" "This application is running test Y" "this emacs is working on this bug" etc.

Comment: Huh, interesting. I've never heard of such a thing, but it sounds like it might be implemented as a feature of a window manager.

Comment: Great idea -- I like it.  ( I also haven't heard of anything like this. )

Comment: I've never heard of it either, but it's something that I've wanted for a long time... Maybe one of these days I'll get around to just writing the thing...

Comment: well... the inverse exists... their's kde activities which allows you to assign apps to an activity. Then you can start and stop those activities... but otherwise I've never heard of anything like this

Comment: I don't know, but for that purpose I use the virtual desktops and organize things so that project X apps/windows are all in one virtual desktop, project Y in another. The desktops can be labeled (using the virtual desktop configuration editor) for each project as well.

Answer (score 4):

Sun's Project Looking Glass had this feature (or something *very* close to it) but is now more or less dead, sadly.

One possible way to achieve a similar result would be to use a window manager that allows you to tab windows together (Fluxbox comes to mind), and tab a text editor or other notes app to each window, and use that for your notes.